# JavaScript - Improve the URL parameter fetching algorithm

Tags: javascript, search, url

I need to get the URL search paramentes in an object, for eg; `http://example.com/?a=x&b=y&d#pqr` should yield `{a:x, b:y, d:1}`

Below is the method i used to get this, How can i improve this? any suggessions...

```
        var urlParamKeyVals = new Array();
        var pieces          = new Array();
        var UrlParams = {};
        if(window.location.search.length){
            var urlSearchString = window.location.search;
            if(urlSearchString.charAt(0) == '?'){
                urlSearchString = urlSearchString.substr(1);
                urlParamKeyVals = urlSearchString.split("&");
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i<urlParamKeyVals .length; i++) {
            pieces = urlParamKeyVals [i].split("=");
            if(pieces.length==1){
                UrlParams[pieces[0]]=1;
            } else {
                UrlParams[pieces[0]]=pieces[1];
            }
        }
        UrlParams;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some time ago a small function for the same purpose:

**Edit:** To handle *empty keys* as `1`:

```
function getQueryStringValues (str) {
  str = str || window.location.search;
  var result = {};

  str.replace(/([^?=&]+)(?:[&#]|=([^&#]*))/g, function (match, key, value) {
    result[key] = value || 1;
  });

  return result;
}


getQueryStringValues("http://example.com/?a=x&b=c&d#pqr");
// returns { a="x",  b="c",  d=1 }
```

Comment: @sje397: Yes, but I would use `decodeURIComponent` instead of `unescape`.

Comment: `getQueryStringValues("http://example.com/?a&b=y&d#pqr")` outputs `{b:'y'}`, it should be `{a:1,b:'y':d:1}`

Comment: Now `getQueryStringValues("http://example.com/?a&b=c&d#pqr");` outputs correct `{a:1,b:'y':d:1}`.

But `getQueryStringValues("http://example.com/?a=x&b=c&d#pqr");` outputs `{a:'x', a=x:1,b:'y':d:1}`

Answer (score 2):

```
function getParams(q){
   var p, reg = /[?&]([^=#&]+)(?:=([^&#]*))?/g, params = {};

   while(p = reg.exec(q)){
      params[decodeURIComponent(p[1])] = p[2] ? decodeURIComponent(p[2]) : 1;
   }
   return params;
}
getParams(location.search);
```

-- edit
I extended the regular expression to match also the &param (no value) and &param= (empty value) cases. In both cases the value 1 is returned. It should also stop extracting on hash (#) character. Decoding values also supported.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please check the new version of the function.

Comment: After the update `getParams('http://example.com?a=x&b=y&d#pqr');` outputs `{a:'x', b:'y', d#pqr:'undefined'}`

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy everything from the console. Now it should output 1 for empty 'd' param and empty string for "param=" case.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery bbq has a nice deparam method if you are trying to look at some very stable code:

- http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/
- http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/

Answer (score 1):

```
function getObjectFromSearch() {
  var search = location.search;
  var searchTerms = [];
  var obj = {};
  if (search !== '') {
    search = search.replace(/^\?/,'');
    searchTerms = search.split("&");
  }
  for (var i=0, imax=searchTerms.length; i<imax; i++) {
    var ary = searchTerms[i].split("=");
    obj[ary[0]] = ary[1];
  }
  return obj;
}
```